# Excel 2016 Macros - Windows/Mac Issue

Tags: microsoft-office, macros, certificate, microsoft-excel-2016

I'm using Excel 2016 (Desktop - not online) and I've created a worbook with a Macro that I've signed using a self-signed certificate.

I've set the 'trust center' settings on Windows so it will only run the Macro if it's been digitally signed and the certificate is trusted.

I want to run the same Macro on the Mac version of Excel 2016, however I can't find any 'trust center' settings. I only seem to be able to enable or disable macros?

Has anyone got a solution to this?

Comment: Are there there settings for this in the `Preferences` > `Sharing and Privacy` menu?

Comment: @CharlieRB it only gives the option to enable/disable, no granular controls like Windows. I'm assuming this is a shortcoming on the Mac version.

Comment: I believe you are correct.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else who is having this issue, it appears that Excel in Office 2016 for OSX only allows you to enable or disable macros completely.

It does not offer the option to only run 'digitally signed macros' like it's Windows counterpart. Therefore it renders the security aspect of having digitally-signed macros useless.

Answer (score 0):

As others mentioned, this doesn't appear to be possible.

To prevent the "Enable / Disable macros" popup, you can go to Excel -> Preferences -> Security -> Enable all macros.

However, this is obviously not great in terms of security.