# Enable macros for specific Excel file

Tags: microsoft-excel, security, microsoft-excel-2007, macros

(How) Can I enable macros in *one* Excel (2007) file?

Disabling macro security through the Trust Center allows macros on *all* spreadsheets. I can set it to 'Disable all macros with notifications' but then Excel will automatically block the macros in my file and I have to go through the *Security Warning / Options / Enable this content* every time:

[image]

I don't want to use the [Trusted locations](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-remove-or-change-a-trusted-location-for-your-files-f5151879-25ea-4998-80a5-4208b3540a62) feature, because the file moves between physical locations.
<strike>For the same reason, digital certificates as mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10047714/excel-2007-enable-macros-for-a-single-excel-document) are not an option.</strike>

Saving the file as an *Excel macro-enabled workbook* (`.xlsm` extension) does not make a difference.

Comment: If you are using Excel 2003 or 2007 you should be able to set the file to "Ask each time", see here: http://www.exceltrick.com/how_to/enable-macros-in-excel/

Comment: @ejbytes Yes, but I'd prefer it to not ask each time

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Even though the file moves around, you can use a digital certificate to sign your macro project using a certificate from a trusted [CA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_authority).

Actually the **purpose** of the function in MS Office to digitally sign macros projects is so that it runs from any location which has trusted macros enabled and run it without a warning.

Without digitally signing, there is no way, you can have it run on any workstation without any warning since that defeats the whole purpose of security built around macros.

Here is how you can digitally sign your macro project:

1. Open the file that contains the macro project that you want to sign.
2. On the `Developer` tab, in the `Code` group, click `Visual Basic`.
3. In Visual Basic, on the `Tools` menu, click `Digital Signature`. The Digital Signature dialog appears.
4. Select a certificate and click OK.

**Notes:**

a) If the Developer tab is not available: Click the `File` tab. Click `Options`. Click `Customize Ribbon`. In the Customize the Ribbon list, click `Developer`, and then click OK.

b) If you haven't selected a digital certificate or want to use another, click `Choose`. Select a certificate and click OK.

c) It is recommended that you sign macros only after your solution has been tested and ready for distribution: when code in a signed macro project is changed in any way, its digital signature is removed. However, if you have the valid digital certificate that was previously used to sign the project on your computer, the macro project is automatically re-signed when you save it.

d) If you want to prevent users of your solution from accidentally changing your macro project and invalidating your signature, lock the macro project before you sign it. Your digital signature implies that you guarantee the project has not been tampered with since you signed it. Your digital signature does not prove that you wrote the project. Therefore, locking your macro project doesn't prevent another user from replacing the digital signature with another signature. Corporate administrators can re-sign templates and add-ins so that they can control what users run on their computers.

e) If you create an add-in that adds code to a macro project, your code should determine if the project is digitally signed and should notify the users of the consequences of changing a signed project before they continue.
When you digitally sign macros, it is important to obtain a time stamp so that other users can verify your signature if the certificate used for the signature has expired, or has been revoked after signing. If you sign macros without a time stamp, the signature remains valid during the validity period of your certificate.

f) Note that [Digitally signing your macro project](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Digitally-sign-your-macro-project-956e9cc8-bbf6-4365-8bfa-98505ecd1c01) is different from [trusted locations](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-remove-or-change-a-trusted-location-for-your-files-f5151879-25ea-4998-80a5-4208b3540a62).

**References:**

- [Digitally sign your macro project](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Digitally-sign-your-macro-project-956e9cc8-bbf6-4365-8bfa-98505ecd1c01)

Comment: I'm missing the `Digital Signature` button in the Tools-menu. Maybe an issue with Mac Excel?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is possible on Windows (see comments by others).

On Mac, granular controls don't appear to be available (see also [Excel 2016 Macros - Windows/Mac Issue](https://superuser.com/questions/1042448/excel-2016-macros-windows-mac-issue/) ).

To prevent the "Enable / Disable macros" popup, you can go to Excel -> Preferences -> Security -> Enable all macros.

However, this is obviously not great in terms of security.